# What is wrong in chrome "net : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR"?

Tags: php, html, spdy

Page on URL **https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie.html** cannot load in Chrome properly. When I look to console in devtools there is 5 times an error : "**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR**" .

Because of that 5 thumbnails of pictures of 5 galleries don't appear on screen. I can find what requests are behind these errors. It is for example GET of "**https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/fotogalerie/2018/Kromeriz/img00001.jpg&w=120&h=120&hash=fb0137670311c4ace04dce839d03701e**" .

Because it is all about website hosting it could be hard to debug. But I think there is a Nginx and than Apache with PHP. The phpThumbnailer is requested by Chrome from HTML source. What should be my steps to solve this problem?

I searched google but I'm rather confused than clever from that. So I decided to ask here.

include lines 108-132 of https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie.html

```
<div class="panelGaleries" align="justify">
                <span class="orangetitle">Fotogalerie za rok 2018</span><br /><br />
                <span class="bodytext"> 
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/Kromeriz" class="linkPhotos jquery" title="O poklad hanáckých Atén"><img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/fotogalerie/2018/Kromeriz/img00001.jpg&w=120&h=120&hash=fb0137670311c4ace04dce839d03701e" alt="O poklad hanáckých Atén" /></a><a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/Kromeriz" class="galeriesLink jquery">O poklad hanáckých Atén</a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>   
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/Chodov" class="linkPhotos jquery" title="Majorettes Chodov"><img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/fotogalerie/2018/Chodov/img00001.jpg&w=120&h=120&hash=58dadfc8c122ee14c51487e5987a43d0" alt="Majorettes Chodov" /></a><a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/Chodov" class="galeriesLink jquery">Majorettes Chodov</a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>   
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/Kolin" class="linkPhotos jquery" title="Kmochův Kolín"><img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/fotogalerie/2018/Kolin/img00001.jpg&w=120&h=120&hash=e540c90e1f1608608984fcaeb8a3093f" alt="Kmochův Kolín" /></a><a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/Kolin" class="galeriesLink jquery">Kmochův Kolín</a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>   
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/MS" class="linkPhotos jquery" title="IFMS - Mistrovství světa"><img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/fotogalerie/2018/MS/img00001.jpg&w=120&h=120&hash=8f9f4b9fcd7d06a760c5c068cd413363" alt="IFMS - Mistrovství světa" /></a><a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/MS" class="galeriesLink jquery">IFMS - Mistrovství světa</a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>   
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/wannado" class="linkPhotos jquery" title="Wannado festival"><img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/fotogalerie/2018/wannado/img00001.jpg&w=120&h=120&hash=ddae43d181ff7378fed770527a92714d" alt="Wannado festival" /></a><a href="https://www.topmazoretkypraha.com/fotogalerie/2018/wannado" class="galeriesLink jquery">Wannado festival</a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>   
                </span>
            </div>
```

there should be no error when data is loaded, but still there is

Comment: Hey, there is another hint for you who try to solve this -> the error appears after web hosting went to HTTPS from HTTP.

Comment: I tryied to disable spdy protocol on server side, but it ended with internal server error. Maybe it can be disabled only in virtualhost section but i tried it in .htaccess file because of web hosting limits.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that problem is with avast? See, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sfAqeo4hDy8 . So this issue cannot be solved - how can I turn avast off on server side with PHP?! Can anyone remove Chrome from the whole world? It could be the right solution...i think

Comment: Yes, the solution is "uninstall chrome". You know I thought maybe Firefox does not use or knows that awesome SPDY protocol, but it uses and understands it and there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that web hosting adds HTTP header `Content-Encoding: gzip` for all the PHP content even when the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` is in the output from that script. For the hotfix I added HTTP header `Content-Encoding: none` into that script. And it worked. But now I am asking web hosting provider to not add the wrong header if `Content-Type: image/jpeg` is present. At HTTPS it makes sense.